# is there a subtitling feature in Agora.io?

Tags: agora.io, videocall

I have implemented video call functionality using agora sdk. I would like to know if there is a feature where i can see real time subtitling like microsoft cognitive services? or a translation feature for real time subtitling. Even if there is a lag its fine. How do it do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To show live captions on your call. Please use extensions provided by agora i.e. Symbl.ai